# Short selling volume reports

Tags: equities, data, short-selling

I'm researching short selling volume data reports from NYSE, NASDAQ and BATS (Sources: FINRA + BATS website). And my question is: **Why are those numbers so high?**

Is it really just a speculative short selling or a big piece is made from another transactions - like insider selling due Securities Act of 1933 prohibiting direct selling of securities obtained from issuer (so they are shown like shorts to regulators).

Compared to **short interest** (published 2 times per month) those numbers are insane.

I attach a chart with **short volume as a percentage of total volume** reported to FINRA and by BATS (**this volume is significantly lower than total volume published by Bloomberg** - what might be another reason) But distribution of short selling should be approximately same across trading venues right? (excl. darkpools of course)

[image: Alcoa short volume]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who also need an answer as I did. The explanation is here:

https://investorshub.advfn.com/boards/read_msg.aspx?message_id=57101068

TLDR: Those data are +- worthless because not only actual short sales (speculations) are included.